# Parsing Invoke-Restmethod XML SOAP Request (Risport70 CUCM if that helps)

Tags: powershell, soap, invoke-restmethod, cucm

I've run into a weird scenario when trying to pull real time info on phones. I can grab the data just fine and drill down into it but run into an issue I'm not sure how to work around.

Here's a sample XML response Cisco provides. After <ns1:CMNodes> in powershell, I cant drill down further or search the nodes. It turns all the fields underneath into essentially one big string.

[image]

Heres my powershell code to invoke the rest-method

```
$RisBody = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=`"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`" xmlns:soap=`"http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap`">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:selectCmDevice>
         <soap:StateInfo></soap:StateInfo>
         <soap:CmSelectionCriteria>
            <soap:MaxReturnedDevices>1000</soap:MaxReturnedDevices>
            <soap:DeviceClass>Phone</soap:DeviceClass>
            <soap:Model>255</soap:Model>
            <soap:Status>Any</soap:Status>
            <soap:NodeName></soap:NodeName>
            <soap:SelectBy>Name</soap:SelectBy>
            <soap:SelectItems>
               <soap:item>
                  <soap:Item>SEPABCDEF123456</soap:Item>
               </soap:item>
            </soap:SelectItems>
            <soap:Protocol>Any</soap:Protocol>
            <soap:DownloadStatus>Any</soap:DownloadStatus>
         </soap:CmSelectionCriteria>
      </soap:selectCmDevice>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"

$RisRequest = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://CUCM:8443/realtimeservice2/services/RISService70?wsdl' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $RisBody
```

To drill down all the way to CMNodes, I use $RisInfo.Envelope.Body.selectCmDeviceResponse.selectCmDeviceReturn.SelectCmDeviceResult.cmnodes

Heres a look into the output I'm given (removed sensitive info for InnerXML and OuterXML but the values above in the cisco picture all smushed together and unreadable)

```
Name            : ns1:CmNodes
LocalName       : CmNodes
NamespaceURI    : http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap
Prefix          : ns1
NodeType        : Element
ParentNode      : SelectCmDeviceResult
OwnerDocument   : #document
IsEmpty         : False
Attributes      : {}
HasAttributes   : False
SchemaInfo      : System.Xml.XmlName
InnerXml        : Phone INFO
NextSibling     : 
PreviousSibling : TotalDevicesFound
Value           : 
ChildNodes      : {Cucm1, cucm2, cucm3, cucm4}
FirstChild      : item
LastChild       : item
HasChildNodes   : True
IsReadOnly      : False
OuterXml        : Phone INFO
BaseURI         : 
PreviousText    :
```

The results I want to look at our inner/outer xml but they are "strings" (via getType()) which makes it impossible to search via select node. Am I just going to have to parse it out the rough way?

I've tried using invoke-webrequest as well to see if it made any difference but got the same result. Also tried to convert inner/outerxml to [xml] but usually would fail or give me the same structure of string output. Seems like the RisPort70 just puts everything to strings after CMNodes.

Thank you!

Edit-Added .innerxml raw code for view.

```
    <ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>IPAddress1</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChange>false</
ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.co
m/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>Ok</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>IPAddress1</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices><ns1:item><ns1:Name>SE
PDCC36115199A</ns1:Name><ns1:DirNumber>0435-Registered,0432-Registered</ns1:DirNumber><ns1:DeviceClass>Phone</ns1:DeviceClass><ns1:Model>683</ns1:Model
><ns1:Product>568</ns1:Product><ns1:BoxProduct>0</ns1:BoxProduct><ns1:Httpd>Yes</ns1:Httpd><ns1:RegistrationAttempts>0</ns1:RegistrationAttempts><ns1:I
sCtiControllable>true</ns1:IsCtiControllable><ns1:LoginUserId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:Status>Registere
d</ns1:Status><ns1:StatusReason>0</ns1:StatusReason><ns1:PerfMonObject>2</ns1:PerfMonObject><ns1:DChannel>0</ns1:DChannel><ns1:Description>John Doe</
ns1:Description><ns1:H323Trunk><ns1:ConfigName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:TechPrefix xmlns:xsi="http://ww
w.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:Zone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:RemoteCmServer1 xmln
s:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:RemoteCmServer2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" 
/><ns1:RemoteCmServer3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:AltGkList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-i
nstance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:ActiveGk xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:CallSignalAddr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.o
rg/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><ns1:RasAddr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:H323Trunk><ns1:TimeSta
mp>1662497967</ns1:TimeStamp><ns1:Protocol>SIP</ns1:Protocol><ns1:NumOfLines>2</ns1:NumOfLines><ns1:LinesStatus><ns1:item><ns1:DirectoryNumber>0432</ns
1:DirectoryNumber><ns1:Status>Registered</ns1:Status></ns1:item><ns1:item><ns1:DirectoryNumber>0432</ns1:DirectoryNumber><ns1:Status>Registered</ns1:St
atus></ns1:item></ns1:LinesStatus><ns1:ActiveLoadID>sip88xx.14-1-1-0001-125</ns1:ActiveLoadID><ns1:InactiveLoadID>sip88xx.12-7-1-0001-393</ns1:Inactive
LoadID><ns1:DownloadStatus>Successful</ns1:DownloadStatus><ns1:DownloadFailureReason xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" 
/><ns1:DownloadServer>IPAddress7</ns1:DownloadServer><ns1:IPAddress><ns1:item><ns1:IP>IPAddress6</ns1:IP><ns1:IPAddrType>ipv4</ns1:IPAddrType><ns1:
Attribute>Unknown</ns1:Attribute></ns1:item></ns1:IPAddress></ns1:item></ns1:CmDevices></ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soa
p"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>IPAddress3</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.
org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
<ns1:Name>IPAddress4</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /><
/ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>IPAddress5</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChan
ge>true</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas
.cisco.com/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>IPAddress8</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChange>true</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xs
i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound
</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>IPAddress9</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>IPAddress10</ns1
:Name><ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:item>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml response as *text*? It’s impossible to test locally with an *image* of some xml, and I’m not typing all of that in by hand :-).

Comment: You might also need to put more representative example text for ```InnerXml``` and ```OuterXml``` - it *looks* like you might have over-anonymised it as I can’t work out where “Phone INFO” comes from in the *picture* of the xml response…

Comment: Did you try `$RisInfo.Envelope.Body.selectCmDeviceResponse.selectCmDeviceReturn.SelectCmDeviceResult.CmNodes.item[0]` ?

Comment: You need to use a real xml library to parse the data.   Post sample of response and I'll  provide the code.

Comment: mclayton, @jdweng, heres a sample of what it looks like but 1 full string as output in powershell.
<ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap"><ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode><ns1:Name>[IP Address]</ns1:Name><ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange><ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" /></ns1:item><ns1:item xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap"<ns1:ReturnCode>Ok</ns1:ReturnCode>

Rich Moss, I tried that but got only the CMnode that the phone is attached to. Nothing regarding the actual output. thank you though!

Comment: I need the entire XML.

Comment: @jdweng, apologies on the late reply. could get to it yesterday. i'v edited the question wit the raw .innerxml output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code using Xml Linq

```
using assembly System
using assembly System.Collections
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

$CmNodes = $doc.Descendants().Where( {$_.Name.LocalName -eq "CmNodes"})[0]
$ns1 = $CmNodes.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns1")
foreach($item in $CmNodes.Elements($ns1 + "item"))
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject

   foreach($node in $item.Descendants())
   {
      $tagName = $node.Name.LocalName
      if(($node.Value.Length -gt 0) -and (-not $node.HasElements))
      {
         # do not add name if already exists
         if($newRow.$tagName -eq $null)
         {
            $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $tagName -NotePropertyValue $node.Value
         }
      }
   }

   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-List
```

Here is the xml I used

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas/xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:selectCmDeviceResponse xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/est/soap">
      <ns1:selectCmDeviceReturn>
        <ns1:selectCmDeviceResult>
          <ns1:TotalDevicesFound>1</ns1:TotalDevicesFound>
          <ns1:CmNodes>
            <ns1:item>
              <ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
              <ns1:Name>IPAddress1</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange>
              <ns1:CmDevices>
                <ns1:item>
                  <ns1:Name>SEPDCC36115199A</ns1:Name>
                  <ns1:DirNumber>0435-Registered,0432-Registered</ns1:DirNumber>
                  <ns1:DeviceClass>Phone</ns1:DeviceClass>
                  <ns1:Model>683</ns1:Model
>
                  <ns1:Product>568</ns1:Product>
                  <ns1:BoxProduct>0</ns1:BoxProduct>
                  <ns1:Httpd>Yes</ns1:Httpd>
                  <ns1:RegistrationAttempts>0</ns1:RegistrationAttempts>
                  <ns1:IsCtiControllable>true</ns1:IsCtiControllable>
                  <ns1:LoginUserId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                  <ns1:Status>Registered</ns1:Status>
                  <ns1:StatusReason>0</ns1:StatusReason>
                  <ns1:PerfMonObject>2</ns1:PerfMonObject>
                  <ns1:DChannel>0</ns1:DChannel>
                  <ns1:Description>John Doe</ns1:Description>
                  <ns1:H323Trunk>
                    <ns1:ConfigName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:TechPrefix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:Zone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:RemoteCmServer1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:RemoteCmServer2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1"/>
                    <ns1:RemoteCmServer3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:AltGkList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:ActiveGk xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:CallSignalAddr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                    <ns1:RasAddr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
                  </ns1:H323Trunk>
                  <ns1:TimeStamp>1662497967</ns1:TimeStamp>
                  <ns1:Protocol>SIP</ns1:Protocol>
                  <ns1:NumOfLines>2</ns1:NumOfLines>
                  <ns1:LinesStatus>
                    <ns1:item>
                      <ns1:DirectoryNumber>0432</ns1:DirectoryNumber>
                      <ns1:Status>Registered</ns1:Status>
                    </ns1:item>
                    <ns1:item>
                      <ns1:DirectoryNumber>0432</ns1:DirectoryNumber>
                      <ns1:Status>Registered</ns1:Status>
                    </ns1:item>
                  </ns1:LinesStatus>
                  <ns1:ActiveLoadID>sip88xx.14-1-1-0001-125</ns1:ActiveLoadID>
                  <ns1:InactiveLoadID>sip88xx.12-7-1-0001-393</ns1:InactiveLoadID>
                  <ns1:DownloadStatus>Successful</ns1:DownloadStatus>
                  <ns1:DownloadFailureReason xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1"/>
                  <ns1:DownloadServer>IPAddress7</ns1:DownloadServer>
                  <ns1:IPAddress>
                    <ns1:item>
                      <ns1:IP>IPAddress6</ns1:IP>
                      <ns1:IPAddrType>ipv4</ns1:IPAddrType>
                      <ns1:Attribute>Unknown</ns1:Attribute>
                    </ns1:item>
                  </ns1:IPAddress>
                </ns1:item>
              </ns1:CmDevices>
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item>
              <ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
              <ns1:Name>IPAddress3</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange>
              <ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item>
              <ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
              <ns1:Name>IPAddress4</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange>
              <ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item>
              <ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
              <ns1:Name>IPAddress5</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:NoChange>true</ns1:NoChange>
              <ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item>
              <ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
              <ns1:Name>IPAddress8</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:NoChange>true</ns1:NoChange>
              <ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item>
              <ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
              <ns1:Name>IPAddress9</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange>
              <ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
            </ns1:item>
            <ns1:item>
              <ns1:ReturnCode>NotFound</ns1:ReturnCode>
              <ns1:Name>IPAddress10</ns1:Name>
              <ns1:NoChange>false</ns1:NoChange>
              <ns1:CmDevices xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
            </ns1:item>
          </ns1:CmNodes>
        </ns1:selectCmDeviceResult>
      </ns1:selectCmDeviceReturn>
    </ns1:selectCmDeviceResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the results

```
ReturnCode           : NotFound
Name                 : IPAddress1
NoChange             : false
DirNumber            : 0435-Registered,0432-Registered
DeviceClass          : Phone
Model                : 683
Product              : 568
BoxProduct           : 0
Httpd                : Yes
RegistrationAttempts : 0
IsCtiControllable    : true
Status               : Registered
StatusReason         : 0
PerfMonObject        : 2
DChannel             : 0
Description          : John Doe
TimeStamp            : 1662497967
Protocol             : SIP
NumOfLines           : 2
DirectoryNumber      : 0432
ActiveLoadID         : sip88xx.14-1-1-0001-125
InactiveLoadID       : sip88xx.12-7-1-0001-393
DownloadStatus       : Successful
DownloadServer       : IPAddress7
IP                   : IPAddress6
IPAddrType           : ipv4
Attribute            : Unknown

ReturnCode : NotFound
Name       : IPAddress3
NoChange   : false

ReturnCode : NotFound
Name       : IPAddress4
NoChange   : false

ReturnCode : NotFound
Name       : IPAddress5
NoChange   : true

ReturnCode : NotFound
Name       : IPAddress8
NoChange   : true

ReturnCode : NotFound
Name       : IPAddress9
NoChange   : false

ReturnCode : NotFound
Name       : IPAddress10
NoChange   : false
```

Comment: first time using .net assemblies in Powershell. if wanted to use a variable, $Risxml that i've converted to an xml doc, how would I load that? It seems the ::load is looking for a local file.

$Risinfo = $RisRequest.Envelope.Body.selectCmDeviceResponse.selectCmDeviceReturn.SelectCmDeviceResult.cmnodes.innerxml
$Risxml = convertto-xml $Risinfo

Comment: sorry, couldnt edit my initial comment. I've tried export-clixml to a .xml file then loading it. seems to work on the load phase but then cmnodes variable becomes null looking for "descendants".

Comment: The node name is case sensitive.  I'm looking for the name without the namespace : "CmNodes".  Either you are using the wrong xml file or "CmNodes" is spelled wrong.  You do not need to write to file.  Instead change Load(filename) to Parse(string).